# How to configure Nuxt app i18n localization with a subdirectory base?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I'm building a blog on Nuxt that runs on a subdirectory (example.com/blog). Now I need to enable i18n module but I'm struggling with the URL structure.

How can I achive to run an "en" language under example.com/**en**/blog and "se" language under example.com/**se**/blog?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you tried so far? Checked the documentation for that?

Comment: This will have all the answers you need https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the Nuxt/i18n module's documentation says about routing:

> @nuxtjs/i18n overrides Nuxt default routes to add locale prefixes to every URL (except in no_prefix strategy).

*Source: [@nuxt/i18n - Routing](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/routing)*

To illustrate, let's follow the example you provided with the following folder structure:

```
project folder/
    pages/
     ---- index.vue/
     ---- blog.vue/
```

In order to build the application's routes, Nuxt/i18n will read the locales provided on your `nuxt.config.js`, and build the routes accordingly (See [the documentation](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/routing) to visualize the built routes).

This means that if you provide two locales (ie. `fr` and `en`) to your config file, and we assume that `en` is the default, you'll end up with the following route structure:

**EN Routes**

- localhost:3000/
- localhost:3000/blogs

**FR Routes**

- localhost:3000/fr
- localhost:3000/fr/blogs

For clarification, here's the documentation on how to configure your i18n module on your `nuxt.config.js` file:

- https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/basic-usage